# What's the use of AES 256 for Zip files

Tags: security, encryption

Will it help if I compress Data files using AES 256 Encryption method as all a programmer has to do is try all sorts of combinations (brute force) to check if the Zip File gets Extracted. Each iteration may take few milli seconds.

Comment: You do not compress the files with AES. You encrypt the archive.

Comment: Brute-forcing a 16-character passphrase that has a least one upper-case letter, one lower-case letter, one number, and one special character will require 1.41 hundred million centuries to crack assuming a cracking array making one hundred trillion guesses per second.

Comment: Modern archivers likely use a complexity increasing function and tune its parameters to make the operation expensive on current hardware. 1ms/attempt means only 1000 attempts per second, which is only good for dictionary-based attacks. Brute-forcing even a 5-letter alphanumeric password at that rate would take 20 days. For meaningful brute-forcing you want billions(?) of attempts per second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume that you have to try half the key space, you have to try 2^255 combinations. If each combination takes you a millisecond, that's 1.8*10^66 years. Making it a trillion times faster doesn't even make a dent in the timeframe required.

It's simply not feasible to brute force modern crypto.